# Random array with index

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, random, colors

I have a problem I can not solve probably due to exhaustion. In my page I have two boxes in which pressing the "start" button changes the background color randomly without repetition. At first it worked then I changed some things and it no longer works as before. Sometimes I do not make colors appear in the array equal on the two panes. Here is my code

```
function go(){
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * colori.length) + 0);
    var t = Math.floor((Math.random() * colori.length) + 0);
         var sx = document.getElementById("sx");
       var dx = document.getElementById("dx");
       var btngo = document.getElementById("go");

        document.getElementById("scritta").innerHTML = random;
       document.getElementById("scrittaU").innerHTML = t;




       dx.style.backgroud = colori[random];
       sx.style.backgroud = colori[t];

       if(random == t){
       alert("random:"+random+" " +"t"+t);
       alert(colori.splice(random,1));
       random = Math.floor((Math.random() * colori.length) + 0);
       dx.style.background = colori[t];

    sx.style.background = colori[random];
       colori.splice(random,1);
       colori.splice(t,1);

       }

    dx.style.background = colori[t];

    sx.style.background = colori[random];

    colori.splice(random,1);
    colori.splice(random-1,1);

    btngo.disabled=true;
    }
```

Comment: Hard to help you when you only say that it doesn't work

Comment: Basically I randomizes the fotogrefie but sometimes in the two panels leaving two identical

Answer (score 0):

```
 dx.style.backgroud = colori[random];
 sx.style.backgroud = colori[t];
```

Do you mean .background?

Comment: Yes, there are some photos as background

Comment: He's telling you that you misspelled `background`